# Efficient product of 1D array and 3D array along one dimension - NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, multiplication

I have two numpy arrays:

- A 1D array called t of shape (70L,) with element called let s say ti
- A 3D array called I with shape (70L, 1024L, 1024L), with each elements called Ii. Ii are thus of dimension (1024L, 1024L)

I would like to make a product of the two array along the first dimension, i.e.:

```
tI = t1*I1,t2*I2,...,tN*IN
```

such as to obtain again a new array of dimension (70L, 1024L, 1024L) and then take the sum along the first dimension in order to obtain an array of dimension  (1024L, 1024L):

```
tsum = t1*I1 + t2*I2 + ... +tN*IN
```

For the moment I am satisfied with doing the following:

```
tI = np.asarray([t[i]*I[i,:,:] for i in range(t.shape[0])])
tsum = np.sum(tI,axis=0)
```

But it is going to be a bit slow is the dimensions of my array are increasing. 
I was wondering if there exist a numpy or scipy function, more optimized for that particular task?

Thanks in advance of any link or information.

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(t,I, axes=([0],[0]))
```

You can also use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('i,ijk->jk',t,I)
```

Runtime test and output verification -

```
In [21]: def original_app(t,I):
    ...:     tI = np.asarray([t[i]*I[i,:,:] for i in range(t.shape[0])])
    ...:     tsum = np.sum(tI,axis=0)
    ...:     return tsum
    ...: 

In [22]: # Inputs with random elements
    ...: t = np.random.rand(70,)
    ...: I = np.random.rand(70,1024,1024)
    ...: 

In [23]: np.allclose(original_app(t,I),np.tensordot(t,I, axes=([0],[0])))
Out[23]: True

In [24]: np.allclose(original_app(t,I),np.einsum('i,ijk->jk',t,I))
Out[24]: True

In [25]: %timeit np.tensordot(t,I, axes=([0],[0]))
1 loops, best of 3: 110 ms per loop

In [26]: %timeit np.einsum('i,ijk->jk',t,I)
1 loops, best of 3: 201 ms per loop
```

Comment: For me `tensordot` is actually faster.

Comment: @egpbos Did you try with the same datasizes? I think it could be the way NumPy was compiled during installation. For different hardware, it might perform differently, mostly a guess though.

Comment: Yeah, I just copied your test code. `tensordot` is consistently about 35% faster than `einsum` for me.

    `In [65]: %timeit np.einsum('i,ijk->jk',t,I)
    10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop

    In [66]: %timeit np.tensordot(t,I, axes=([0],[0]))
    10 loops, best of 3: 65.9 ms per loop`

Comment: @egpbos Hmm interesting results. I am guessing hardware has to play a big role in it.

Comment: hei, thanks. np.tensordot did it for me and for me to it was faster than einsum

Answer (score 2):

Divakar gives the best (most efficient) answers. For completeness' sake, one other way of doing it is by using [Numpy's broadcasting capabilities](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
(t[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*I).sum(axis=0)
```

By adding two axes to `t`, broadcasting becomes possible and one can use regular Numpy operations, which for some might be more readable.

Comment: And that `broadcasting` is a great feature too with NumPy! Love that one.